# Overloading a method in C#

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

I'm working on an assignment and I am stuck on the overload my method to repeat it `nth` times thats specified in the `main`. I have the last method in my class called `Collatz` wrapped in a `do while` loop but it doesn't seem to be working correctly as it should run the loop x amount of times as specified in the main method where it is being overloaded. It's the only part I can't figure out. Heres is my `Main`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Collatz thisCollatz = new Collatz(15);
            Console.WriteLine(
                string.Format("Collatz iteration is {0} and value is {1}",
                thisCollatz.Iteration, thisCollatz.CurrentVal));

            thisCollatz.Iterate();
            Console.WriteLine(
                string.Format("Collatz iteration is {0} and value is {1}",
                thisCollatz.Iteration, thisCollatz.CurrentVal));

            //// Overload of iterate method
            thisCollatz.Iterate(10);
            Console.WriteLine(
                string.Format("Collatz iteration is {0} and value is {1}",
                thisCollatz.Iteration, thisCollatz.CurrentVal));

            Console.WriteLine("\nPAK..." + "\nProduced By: Jeremy Garcia");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

and here is what I have in my class:

```
class Collatz
    {
        // _Iteration is how many iterations of Collatz have run since initialization
        // _CurrentVal is the current value of the Collatz process
        private int _Iteration;
        private int _CurrentVal;

        public Collatz(int InitialValue)
        // initializer
        {
            CurrentVal = InitialValue;
            Iteration = 0;
        }

        public int CurrentVal
        // returns the current Collatz value or -- within the class -- allows it to be set
        {
            get { return _CurrentVal; }
            private set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                {
                    _CurrentVal = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("CurrentVal is not a positive integer");
                }
            }
        }
        public int Iteration
        // returns the current number of Collatz iterations or 
        //  -- within the class -- allows it to be set
        {
            get { return _Iteration; }
            private set { _Iteration = value; }
        }

        public void Iterate()
        // Executes one iteration of Collatz creating a 
        // new CurrentVal from the existing CurrentVal
        {
            if (_CurrentVal != 1)
            {
                if (_CurrentVal % 2 == 0)
                {
                    _CurrentVal = _CurrentVal / 2;
                    _Iteration ++;
                }
                else if (_CurrentVal % 2 != 0)
                {
                    _CurrentVal = (_CurrentVal * 3) + 1;
                    _Iteration ++;
                }
                else
                {
                    _CurrentVal = 1;
                    _Iteration = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        public void Iterate(int iterations)
        // Check if CurrentVal is (already) 1 -- don't calculate 
        //  new CurrentVal nor increment Iteration if so
        // Otherwise calculate new CurrentVal and increment Iteration
        {
            do
            {
                if (_CurrentVal != 1)
                {
                    if (_CurrentVal % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        _CurrentVal = _CurrentVal / 2;
                        _Iteration++;
                    }
                    else if (_CurrentVal % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        _CurrentVal = (_CurrentVal * 3) + 1;
                        _Iteration++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _CurrentVal = 1;
                        _Iteration = 1;
                    }
                }
            } while (iterations != 0);
        }
    }
```

Thank you for the help in advance. I'm not looking to rewrite the entire program, just simply get the last method to work. Thanks again.

Comment: `doesn't seem to be working` is vague.  gobs of posts to the right under **Related**

Comment: Please expand on what "doesn't seem to be working" means.  We cannot see your screen.  Are you getting errors?  What is the expected behavior, and what is it actually doing?  **Be specific**

Comment: Are you finding your `do-while` just runs forever? - which is what would appear to be the case. Your loop is designed to keep looping while iterations is never equal to zero; and nothing in your code would set your iterations to zero - thus its an infinite loop. Somewhere within you need to either count iterations down or set it to zero, allowing your loop to end.

Comment: As @Plutonix highlight, you haven't described what is going wrong.  Your last method `Iterate()` accepts an argument `iterations` which is passed in `10`.  In the body of that method, the `while` condition will equate to `true` if that value is not equal to 0 - as the value of `iterations` is never changed it looks like this will loop indefinitely.

Comment: Its not running the code the specified number of times (i.e. iterations) specified in the main which is set to 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decrement the iteration counter to avoid infinite looping. Something like:

```
do
{
...
iterations--;
} while (iterations != 0);
```

Comment: Perfect! That works but its showing me 11 iterations when in main it was set to 10. Am I missing something?

Comment: If by 11 iterations you mean the value of  `thisCollatz.Iteration` being 11, it might be because you're already setting it to 1 with your `thisCollatz.Iterate();` call. Remember value of `_Iteration` is shared within the object, and each operation modifies its existing value.

Answer (score 0):

When you're done doing your work, you'll want to make sure you set your `iterations` variable to 0 to get out of your do/while loop.